# Get row number using text in the row in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I have the table structured below

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="checkbox-column"></th>
      <th class="main-column main-column--checkbox">Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="(a, b) in tests" class="ng-scope" style="">
    <tr class="panel__sub-header">
      <td>
        <input name="item-checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelectAll(a)" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td colspan="4">
        <h4 class="ng-binding">ROW2</h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="test in testData" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" class="ng-scope odd" style="">
      <td class="checkbox-column"><input name="item-checkbox" ng-click="checkFunction()" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="main-column">
        <a ng-href="#" class="ng-binding" href="#">test.name</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="test in testData" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" class="ng-scope odd" style="">
      <td class="checkbox-column"><input name="item-checkbox" ng-click="checkFunction()" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="main-column">
        <a ng-href="#" class="ng-binding" href="#">test.data</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody ng-repeat="(a, b) in tests" class="ng-scope" style="">
    <tr class="panel__sub-header">
      <td>
        <input name="item-checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelectAll(a)" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td colspan="4">
        <h4 class="ng-binding">ROW1</h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="test in testData" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" class="ng-scope odd" style="">
      <td class="checkbox-column"><input name="item-checkbox" ng-click="checkFunction()" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="main-column">
        <a ng-href="#" class="ng-binding" href="#">test.name</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="test in testData" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" class="ng-scope odd" style="">
      <td class="checkbox-column"><input name="item-checkbox" ng-click="checkFunction()" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="main-column">
          <a ng-href="#" class="ng-binding" href="#">test.data</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to get the table cell by using the below
`element(by.repeater('(a, b) in tests').row(0)).element(by.css('[xxx]'))`. Currently am using the hard coded row number to achieve this but its not working all the time due to the dynamic UI changes

Is that possible to get the row number using the by passing the text in protractor

Ex:
If I pass the text `ROW2` then it should return the row number as 0 using the repeater `(a, b) in tests` then I can able to use the row number dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing it by getting row number, you can use `filter()` method to get the particular row that contains the expected text.

```
var columnElement = element.all(by.repeater('(a, b) in tests')).filter(function(rowElement){
   return rowElement.element(by.css("td h4")).getText().then(function(text){
    return text.trim() == "ROW2"
  });
}).first().element(by.css("somecss"));
```

Comment: Thanks, also is this possible to expand the same to get the values from nested tables? i.e to get the `tr` for nested repeater `test in testData` using the element `test.name`

Answer (score 1):

Find it by xpath:

```
element(by.repeater('(a, b) in tests').row(0)).element(by.xpath('XXX'))
```

Or

```
function GetRowNumber(yourText)
{
    var items = element(by.repeater('(a, b) in tests')).all(by.tagName('h4')).map(function(elem) {
        return elem.getText();
    });

    return items.then(function(elems){
       for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
       {
          if(elems[i] === yourText)
              return i;
       }
    });
}
```

This code haven't been tested.

Comment: Actually `element(by.xpath('XXX'))` part is not a problem. The need is to get the row number `row(0)` should be get dynamically by using the text present in that row

Answer (score 0):

```
var getRowNumber = function (text) {
    var tbody = element(by.repeater('(a, b) in tests'));
    tbody.filter(function (elem, index) {
       if (!!elem.element(by.cssContainingText('h4', text))) {
          return index;
       }
   })
};
console.log('row number :'+ getRowNumber('ROW2'));
```