# Get the element using the text in the row in Protractor from nested repeater

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I have the table structured below

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="checkbox-column"></th>
      <th class="main-column main-column--checkbox">Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="(a, b) in tests" class="ng-scope" style="">
    <tr class="panel__sub-header">
      <td>
        <input name="item-checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelectAll(a)" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td colspan="4">
        <h4 class="ng-binding">ROW2</h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="test in testData" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" class="ng-scope odd" style="">
      <td class="checkbox-column"><input name="item-checkbox" ng-click="checkFunction()" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="main-column">
        <a ng-href="#" class="ng-binding" href="#">test.name</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="test in testData" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" class="ng-scope odd" style="">
      <td class="checkbox-column"><input name="item-checkbox" ng-click="checkFunction()" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="main-column">
        <a ng-href="#" class="ng-binding" href="#">test.data</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody ng-repeat="(a, b) in tests" class="ng-scope" style="">
    <tr class="panel__sub-header">
      <td>
        <input name="item-checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelectAll(a)" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td colspan="4">
        <h4 class="ng-binding">ROW1</h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="test in testData" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" class="ng-scope odd" style="">
      <td class="checkbox-column"><input name="item-checkbox" ng-click="checkFunction()" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="main-column">
        <a ng-href="#" class="ng-binding" href="#">test.name</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="test in testData" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" class="ng-scope odd" style="">
      <td class="checkbox-column"><input name="item-checkbox" ng-click="checkFunction()" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class="main-column">
          <a ng-href="#" class="ng-binding" href="#">test.data</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have got the root table element by using the below answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41129924/2833311

But failing to get the nested repeater elements.

```
getSpecificNestedCell: function(tableObject, rowText, nestedTableObj, rowText1, columnCss) {
    var ele = element.all(by.repeater(tableObject)).filter(function(rowElement){
      return rowElement.element(by.css("td h4")).getText().then(function(text){
        return text.indexOf(rowText) !== -1;
      });
    }).first();

    ele = ele.all(by.repeater(nestedTableObj)).filter(function(rowElement1){
        return rowElement1.element(by.linkText(rowText1)).getText().then(function(text1){
          return text1.indexOf(rowText1) !== -1;
        });
      }).first().element(by.css('[' + columnCss + ']'));

    findObject.waitUntilReady(ele);
    return ele;   }
```

Where as,

1. tableObject  ==> (a, b) in tests
2. rowText  ==> ROW2
3. nestedTableObj ==> test in testData
4. rowText1  ==> test.data
5. columnCss  ==> ng-click="checkFunction()"

Using the above code I could able to get the element if it has the single row inside the nested repeated, but it was failing to get the element when the nested repeater has the multiple rows

Comment: Why you using body tag twice?

Comment: That was the design by the dev team

Comment: What is the difference between first body tag and second body tag? both are same. then why you want?

Comment: Actually, that was drawn by the root repeater `(a, b) in tests` and it can be n numbers.
I just hard coded the same twice for the understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should give you what you want I believe

```
function getSpecificNestedCell(tableObject, rowText, nestedTableObj, rowText1, columnCss) {
   return element(by.cssContainingText('tbody[ng-repeat="' + tableObject + '"]', rowText))
   .element(by.cssContainingText('tr[ng-repeat="' + nestedTableObj + '"]', rowText1))
   .element(by.css('[' + columnCss + ']'));
}
```

Here is the selector I used working
[image]